# Blackberry API / MenuItems

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, menuitem

I'm just learning the blackbery API, trying to follow the tutorials on the blackberry dev site, and I am a bit confused.  In the interface tutorial they give the following instruction for making menu items...

```
private MenuItem _changeCapitol = new MenuItem("Change Capitol", 110, 10) 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        if (displayed == 0) 
            _canadaCapitol = _input.getText(); 
        else if (displayed == 1) 
            _ukCapitol = _input.getText(); 
        else if (displayed == 2) 
            _usCapitol = _input.getText(); 
    } 
};
```

And that's all peachy and works for now.  The issue is that the method used to create the MenuItem is deprecated.  All of the tutorials appear to be for 4.0.  I wanted to learn to do this the proper way so off I went to the 6.0 API Reference.  I've tried to convert this to the current method but I can't get it quite right.  Here is the closest that I have come...

```
private MenuItem _changecapitol = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Change Capitol"), 110, 10);
changecapitol.setCommand(new Command(CapitolChange()));
class CapitolChange extends CommandHandler
{
    public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context)
    {
        if (displayed == 0) 
            _canadaCapitol = _input.getText(); 
        else if (displayed == 1) 
            _ukCapitol = _input.getText(); 
        else if (displayed == 2) 
            _usCapitol = _input.getText();
    }

}
```

It seems as if there really should be something inside the brackets on the constructor but I can't imagine what that might be.  If I understand the reference properly the functionality goes inside the CommandHandler, so I think I have that part right. The issue right now is that Eclipse is throwing an error on the line before the CapitolChange constructor.

```
changecapitol.setCommand(new Command(CapitolChange()));
```

I'm actually getting multiple errors on this line.  One is a misplaced construct error, and the other claims that after "setCommand" I need an "=".  This is nowhere in the API, and it would seem syntactically wrong.  I'm calling a method and not assigning a value.  Right?  No?  Am I just completely wrong on the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable, you create MenuItem with "_changecapitol" and using it with this changecapitol. correct the typo and check the errors.

Comment: Nice catch on the typo, but it did not change the errors at all.  I'm still getting two errors:

Syntax error on token, misplaced construct
and
Syntax error on token "setCommand",= expected after this token

Answer (score 0):

I think compile error is caused by improper place to have command assigned:

```
changecapitol.setCommand(new Command(CapitolChange()));
```

since it is placed somewhere in class declaration part right after MenuItem member declaration.
Please try to assign command elsewhere, maybe in screen constructor.

Comment: The placement is per the official API reference.